# Freezing application-specific dependencies in Python, virtualenv and pip

Tags: python, flask, virtualenv

How can I have a clean virtualenv for my flask application that contains nothing else than the dependencies of application needs?

I am using Ubuntu and I have a Flask application and when I run command `pip freeze > requirements.txt` the requirements file gets unnecessary files also

This leads to a problem when uploading it on heroku.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: first of all, do you do `pip freeze` when you have activate the virtualenv? like: `source your-venv/bin/activate`? Also, to create a clean virtualenv, just do: `virtualenv your-venv --no-site-packages`, then activate it.

Comment: When you say "unnecessary files", are you also talking about the dependency packages of the packages you explicitly installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make a blank virtualenv.
2. Try to run your program.
3. If there is an import error, install the relevant package, then go to (2) again.
4. You now have a virtualenv with just the packages that are required.  Freeze that.

Answer (score 0):

Another easy way of doing this would be using the `pipreqs`. So what it basically does is it generates pip requirements.txt file based on imports of any project.

1. Install `pipreqs`

   pip install pipreqs
2. Then `pipreqs /path/to/project`

You will have your requirements.txt file generated in your project path.